# How to read strings from a csv file and convert it into a integer array?

Tags: python, string, csv, integer

I am finding the most optimized way to create an integer array with the help of data from a csv file.

The csv file("sample.csv") data is like,

| prediciton1 | prediction2 | prediction3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| low | low | low |
| low | high | high |

where **low** = 1, **high** = 3,

i want to read these data from the csv and make an array that looks like,

```
array =  
[[1,1,1],  
[1,3,3]]
```

```
    import csv
    import sys
    
    num1 = 'low'
    num2 = 'high'
    
    
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('sample.csv', "r"), delimiter=",")
    
    count = 0
    
    for row in csv_file:
    
        if count == 1:
            if num1 == row[0]:
                dat1 = 1
        
            elif num2 == row[0]:
                dat1 = 3
            if num1 == row[1]:
                dat2 = 1
        
            elif num2 == row[1]:
                dat2 = 3
                
            if num1 == row[2]:
                dat3 = 1
        
            elif num2 == row[2]:
                dat3 = 3
        
            
        count = count + 1

    array =[dat1,dat2,dat3]
```

This approach works but seems much inefficient. Finding an alternative and optimized way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `dict` for a lookup and list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
check = {'low': 1, "high": 3}

with open('sample.csv') as infile:
    csv_file = csv.reader(infile)
    next(csv_file) # skip header
    result = [[check[c] for c in row] for row in csv_file]
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution! I would only add that, just in case the CSV contains unwanted values (as it sometimes may happen) I would use `check.get(c)` instead of `check[c]` and so handle later the potential `None` values contained in the `result` array.

Answer (score 1):

As the CSV file is pretty simple, you could even do it without the CSV package:

```
# We open the CSV file
with open('sample.csv') as file:
    # We read all the lines and store them in a list
    lines = file.readlines()

# We remove the CSV header
lines = lines[1:]

# We create the array
array = [
    [{
        'low': 1,
        'high': 3
    }.get(value.strip()) for value in line.split(',')
] for line in lines]

# We print the array
print(array)
```

This would print the following array: `[[1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 3]]`

Note the use of the `dict`'s `get` method to avoid errors just in case the CSV has unwanted values. The array would contain a `None` value in those cases.